# Can I protect T-SQL business logic from SQL Server database administrators and owners

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, database-security

I have a rather complex solution, with a lot of business logic within the SQL Server database, located in stored procedures and views.
As a "old school" data warehouse developer, I have created a n-tier architecture with layers for extract, transform and model(s) etc.

I have to install my solution and the corresponding database within a customer database infrastructure, as opposed to placing the database in a container with limited access by users, keeping my IP protected.
I want to prevent the customer or any employee, from grabbing and reusing the solution components.

Is there a way to encrypt or otherwise hide the actual T-SQL within procedures and views, even for database owners and administrators?

I created a C# console application using Entity Framework, that simply executes hard-coded T-SQL statements, as replacement for the stored procedures and views, but this prevents me from handling database incremental deployments (CI/CD) as intended. But it might be the only way...

Comment: Do you really have to allow customer IT staff to be database owners/administrators?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.
The company doesn't allow cloud-integration, so I have to install the solution on-prem, where the custome owns and manages the database servers (on-prem).

Comment: No you can't do much here. You can create stored procedures with the encrypted option but it is not difficult to get around it. Anybody with sysadmin is exactly that, a sysadmin. That means they can do literally anything they want on the sql server. If they couldn't, then it really wouldn't be a sysadmin. Over the years I have seen this question asked so many times and it has always come down to protecting some uber-secret algorithm that is usually not all that difficult to reverse engineer or even needed to be kept secret.

Comment: Yeah, this is down to legal agreements,  NDAs and licensing agreements.

Comment: Hard to get around people running traces and capturing the queries you run. You could do what SAP did, obfuscate all tables into silly 3 or 4 char names and make no discernable relationships between the tables/columns/rows. Although, they might have not done it on purpose. You could also deploy your procs as CLRs

Comment: @siggemannen CLRs are pretty painless to read also. The assembly file has to be on the machine and the dotnet decompiler makes short work of reading it. Although they are painfully obfuscated since variable names and such get mangled into hard to decipher letters.

Comment: You *could* use sp_oacreate and friends (or clr again) to call some webservice on your own server that injects just in time generate SQL code into your procedures, the code can use cursors and synonyms that keep changing as well as dynamicly generated views that are dropped as soon as everything is finished. Hmm, maybe i should copyright that system

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.

I get your point, and I will not attempt to encrypt or hide T-SQL within a SQL Server database.

I have a C# application as a part of the solution, and I think I'll push all the business logic into a C# assembly and use an ORM (EF, Dapper) and leave only tables and views in the database.

I'll probable maintan a full database locally for development purposes, allowing me do "database development" within the database, and migrate procedues til my C# before publishing a limited/simple database along with the C# assembly.